# Can I travel within Schengen after my visa has been stolen?

Tags: visas, schengen, lost-documents

I am a citizen of the US living in Germany on an Au Pair visa since August 2018. This was recently stolen in February and I have not yet gotten word of my replacement. I am hoping to travel to Sweden soon, and have a valid passport, but I am wondering if I will be stopped and questioned about my lack of visa (which I have reported missing to the authorities).

Comment: Don't you have your Aufenthaltstitel? You should have applied for this immediately after you arrived in Germany. Or was it also stolen?

Comment: This will depend a bit on how you travel. You can drive through Denmark on the bridges with very low risk of anybody wanting to look at papers. Train also good I believe (although I have no recent experience). If you fly I imagine it will be harder. You should carry the police report (or a copy of it).

Answer (score 2):

This can really depend on luck. You are, as a non-EU and non-Schengen citizen, expected to have your passport and proof of residency permit in the same country as you at all times. Whether this is checked could depend on multiple factors: the transit company (train, airline, ...) may want to check, although unlikely, border controls may be temporarily set up again (although I'm unaware of any such controls between Sweden and Germany at the moment, but I don't actively keep up to date on this), or you may just have any other by-chance encounter with authorities where they want to check this.

Put briefly: the few times I've accidentally exited a country without passport or visa in the Schengen area, I've never had a problem. But this should be avoided whenever possible because this luck is not guaranteed.

I would recommend getting in contact with the foreign registration office (Ausländerbehörde) in your city and asking them what you can do.